# DeepCopy::recursiveCopy exception when i run codeception with yii2 framework

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, codeception

When run codeception i got a lots fo errors: DeepCopy\DeepCopy::recursiveCopy.

This is a problem so confuse me!

1. I use codeception play well when i have only 4 unit test case: [image]
2. When i still full up the unit test case story happen..
3. There is 5 unit test in my test class then i got this: [image]

Here is the code :

```
public function testGetComplexItemNeeds() {
    $this->specify('[getComplexItemNeeds] : ', function($expected) {
        $actual = \common\services\ConfigService::getComplexItemNeeds('300001');

        expect('getComplexItemNeeds', $actual)->equals($expected);
    }, ['examples' => [
            [0 => [
                    'gold' => 1,
                    'list' => [
                        300018 => 1,
                    ],
                ]
            ],
    ]]);
}
```

php_error.log:

> PHP 195. DeepCopy\DeepCopy::copyArray($array = array ('0000000025e4802e0000000050ab4f11' => class tests\codeception\frontend\UnitTester { protected $scenario = class Codeception\Scenario { ... }; protected $friends = array (...) }, '0000000025e480490000000050ab4f11' => class Codeception\Scenario { protected $test = class tests\codeception\frontend\service\ConfigServiceTest { ... }; protected $steps = array (...);

xdebug:
 i use xdebug to trace the problem found that when the function `specifyCloneProperties` deep copy the unitTester the php script down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [turn off](https://github.com/Codeception/Specify/blob/master/docs/GlobalConfig.md) deep clone in your `bootstrap.php` file:

```
<?php
// disable deep cloning of properties inside specify block
\Codeception\Specify\Config::setDeepClone(false);
?>
```

Or turn on/off [in the test](https://github.com/Codeception/Specify/blob/master/docs/LocalConfig.md). It's also increased performance of your tests.

Comment: awesome buddy!!! the reason why my test down only because the recur copy????maybe some self-reference?!